# Getting TypeError: this.template.querySelector(...) is null, when calling child component method in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've two simple LWC components:1.Parent - boardPanel & 2. Child- boardComponent. I'm calling child component in parent based on condition:

**boardPanel.html**

```
     <template>
    <lightning-card title="Word Shuffle Game">
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                    <lightning-combobox name="gameMode" label="Game Mode" value={gameModeValue}
                        placeholder="Select Game Mode" options={gameModes} onchange={modeChangeHandler}
                        variant="label-hidden"></lightning-combobox>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Start New Game" title="Start New Game"
                        onclick={startGameHandler} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Restart Game" title="Restart Game" onclick={restartHandler}
                        class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>
            <template if:true={gameModeSelected}>
                <c-board-component></c-board-component>
            </template>
        </p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**boardPanel.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class BoardPanel extends LightningElement {
    gameModeValue = '';
    @track
    gameModeSelected = false;

    get gameModes() {
        return [
            { label: 'Easy', value: 'easy' },
            { label: 'Medium', value: 'medium' },
            { label: 'Hard', value: 'hard' },
        ];
    }

    modeChangeHandler(event) {
        this.gameModeValue = event.detail.value;
    }

    startGameHandler() {
        console.log(`Start game handler`);
        let wordCount = 0;
        
        if (!this.gameModeValue || this.gameModeValue === 'easy') {
            this.gameModeValue = 'easy';
            wordCount = 3;
        } else if (this.gameModeValue === 'medium') {
            wordCount = 6;
        } else if (this.gameModeValue === 'hard') {
            wordCount = 9;
        }
        this.gameModeSelected = true;
        this.template.querySelector('c-board-component').getListOfWords();
    }
```

**boardComponent.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
            <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">WORD: {winWord}</div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

**boardComponent.js**

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class BoardComponent extends LightningElement {
    winWord = 'Hello'
    movesLeft = 3
    result = 'You Win'
    @api
    gameModeValue = '';

    @api
    getListOfWords() {
        console.log('Board Component method called');
        let wordList = ['Salesforce', 'Apex', 'LWC', 'Javascript', 'Aura', 'SOQL', 'SOSL', 'Admin', 'Lightning'];
        console.log(wordList);
    }
}
```

On click of a button **Start New Game** in parent component I'm making the flag true(gameModeSelected=true). And in the same function I want to call method from child component.

The flag is getting true, but getting error at line when trying to call child component method

> TypeError: this.template.querySelector(...) is null

When I don't add condition for child component rendering, there I'm able to child component method. But when added inside condition, not able to call the child method. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait for a render cycle after changing a variable that will trigger a render cycle; it doesn't happen immediately when the assignment occurs. This allows the browser to batch render cycles for optimal performance. The easiest way to wait for a render cycle is to use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => this.template.querySelector('c-board-component').getListOfWords());
```

This will let your method do its thing immediately after the render cycle. Be careful to avoid modifying anything that will call startGameHandler again, or you'll run into an infinite loop.

Edit: Note that this is in violation of [@lwc/lwc/no-async-operation](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/blob/master/docs/rules/no-async-operation.md).

The formal recommendation is to use a lifecycle hook, such as:

```
renderedCallback() {
  if(this.gameModeSelected) {
    this.template.querySelector('c-board-component').getListOfWords());
  }
}
```

You may need to tweak this logic depending on if this fires multiple times.

Alternatively, you can use the async keyword, which lets you pause for a single render cycle when combined with a Promise:

```
async startGameHandler() {
  // other stuff here
  await Promise.resolve();
  this.template.querySelector('c-board-component').getListOfWords());
}
```

Finally, I don't know what the method here is doing, but it's reasonable to presume that you can *probably* call `getListOfWords` in the `connectedCallback` of the `boardComponent`.

```
connectedCallback() {
  this.getListOfWords();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having changed the game mode (from, I assume, false) to true immediately before the execution of the query selector and expecting the template to have already been updated, you have misunderstood how LWC rendering works. This isn't done synchronously, but rather asynchronously. By the time your query is performed no new rendering has happened so naturally there are no "c-board-component" elements to be found.

You need to refactor the flow to ensure that you deal with the list of words at an appropriate time.

It may be possible to use, for example, the [renderedCallback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lifecycle_hooks), though TBH, that is probably more of a hack and not something you should have to rely on in well written LWCs.

**UPDATE**:

Based on the additional code shown, my recommendation is:

1. Always render the child, but pass the "gameStarted" property to it in a new API property on the child.
2. When the game starts (and the child receives the updated game started flag, using an API property setter), have the child raise an event to communicate the list of words back to the parent.
3. Update the parent to handle the list of words event (using an "on" handler) and do whatever it needs to do with them.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events) around how events work.

Comment: I've updated the question with basic code snippets. Basically, what I'm doing. Not showing the child Board component on the screen until the Start Game button is clicked. On Clicking on start game, I want to set the game mode (if not already selected) and load the child component and call child component's method to get the list of words. Hope this clears the requirement.